# MYSQL Query on JSON for specific KEY:VALUE

Tags: mysql, json

Im trying to get a matching record within a json. Its only ever once within the json with that specific key and it looks like this.

```
{"bannerpage":["569"],"menulinkage":"569","clickurl":false,}
```

Im trying to find the matching value of 569 with key as bannerpage. However there's no luck. Just wont play nice.

Here is what i have:

```
$sql->select("* FROM #__banners WHERE state=1 AND params LIKE '%"bannerpage":["$menu"]%'");
```

Using the following snippet works but it checks both bannerpage and menulinkage - i only want the value of **bannerpage**.:

```
AND params LIKE '%{$menu}%'
```

I really hope that make sense.

To break it down even simpler:

How do i write a mysql query where i check for a matching number against this json value:

"bannerpage":["569"]

Thanks to anyone for your help
Jonny

Comment: can you share table structure?

Comment: @Shri i worked it out lol. LIKE '%\"bannerpage\":[\"$menu\"]%' I had to escape the inverted commas. The query was breaking because of that.

Answer (score 1):

I dont normally do this but in this case i will just answer it.

I needed to escape the inverted commas like so. Once i did that the mysql query worked fine.

```
LIKE '%\"bannerpage\":[\"$menu\"]%'
```